# VS2017 says "Type 'Strings' is not a collection"

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I was using WPF with VS2015 and it didn't say "Type 'Strings' is not a collection" before.

But after upgrading VS2015 to VS2017, now it says "Type 'Strings' is not a collection" in Error list panel if i use it in xaml code.

I want to skip warning message in Project property but it doesn't have any error code number.

(For your information, compile and running has no problem)

```
public class Strings
{
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            var result = LocalMsg.CommonManager.GetString(key);
            if (result == null && LocalMsg.MyManager != null)
                result = LocalMsg.MyManager.GetString(key);

            if (result == null && LocalMsg.MySubManager != null)
                result = LocalMsg.MySubManager.GetString(key);

            if (result == null)
                result = "Error";
            else
                result = result.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);

            return result;
        }
    }
}


public class LocalMsg : ObservableObjectBase<LocalMsg>
{

    ....

    public Strings LocalText
    {
        get
        {
            return resources;
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

[image]

---

I'm attaching project sample codes in below link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7tiswp7hvvggl9/LocalMsgTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

To be considered a collection, your class must inherit from [`ICollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will have to implement the appropriate methods and properties.

```
public class Strings:ICollection<String>
{
}
```

For `ICollection<T>`

### Properties

- `Count` - Gets the number of elements contained in the ICollection.
- `IsReadOnly` - Gets a value indicating whether the ICollection is read-only.

### Methods

- `Add(T)` - Adds an item to the ICollection.
- `Clear()` - Removes all items from the ICollection.
- `Contains(T)` - Determines whether the ICollection contains a specific value.
- `CopyTo(T[], Int32)` - Copies the elements of the ICollection to an Array, starting at a particular Array index.
- `GetEnumerator()` - Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.(Inherited from IEnumerable.)
- `Remove(T)` - Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the ICollection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had finished to implement but it still says same error message...

Comment: Without seeing the XAML you are using, I can't be sure.  But the only other thing it could be is that it is actually looking for an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Comment: I see one line of XAML that doesn't include a complete element.  Insufficient to even know where the binding is happening.

Comment: Hi bigtlb, I have attached my project source code in my original article.